# OpenGL rendering Array of Meshes

Tags: java, arrays, object, opengl, for-loop

First of, my problem is that I can't a weird result, of something that should render probably, but doesn't in 3D space.

First of, I create the Array of Mesh_Cube's, which is just a class, that contains a Vector3, then i'm passing the for-loop values into them like this:

```
cubes = new Mesh_Cube[10];
for(int x = 0; x < cubes.length; x++) {
    for(int z = 0; z < cubes.length; z++) {
        cubes[x] = new Mesh_Cube(new Vector3(x,0,z), new Vector3(1,0,1));
        System.out.println(cubes[x].position.x + ", " + cubes[x].position.z);
        //Prints out the right coordinates, in both X and Z.
    }
}
```

Then I render them all in a foreach loop in a glBegin method:
(mc.Render() method, just contains the Vertices to render, in the glBegin())

```
for(Mesh_Cube mc : cubes) {
    mc.Render();
}
```

The final result i'm getting is this:

[image]
The actual result, should be a grid, since I have two for loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array `cubes` only has 10 elements. The rendering algorithm works perfectly fine, it renders out all 10 stored meshes.

The problem is your for loop. The first for loop iterates over all the 10 elements, fine. The nested for loop also iterates over 10 elements but its value is never used to calculate an index in the array. You only use the x index the address an element in the array. Meaning you're constantly recreating the first 10 elements.

I'm not quite familiar with the language you're using, but you should either have a 2 dimensional array of 10*10 elements or a 1 dimensional array of 100 elements. This perhaps-pseudo code should give you an idea:

```
// As you can see I use a 1 dimensional array of 100 elements
cubes = new Mesh_Cube[100];

for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    for(int z = 0; z < 10; z++)
    {
        // Now I'm properly calculating the index of the new object,
        // Taking into account both x and z
        cubes[x * 10 + z] = new Mesh_Cube(new Vector3(x,0,z), new Vector3(1,0,1));
    }
```

Your print statement did work as it did create all the 100 meshes, but it replaced previously created meshes in your array as you kept using the first 10 indices.

As it is a 1 dimensional array the rendering algorithm should work fine as it is. If you're going to use a 2 dimensional array it might need some changing, depending on how the language defined 2 dimensional arrays.

Also, what's up with the downvotes people?

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate your time and effort to write an answer for my question. Also, it worked with your code, which is great.